# I Am Unsure Why My Fetch-Post Request is Giving Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, rest

I am really confused since I have used a fetch request many times before and (I think) it should have been fine. Obviously there is an issue. The structure is...

auth.js

```
function AuthUp()
{

    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    console.log(pass);

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/SignUp', {
        method:"POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(pass),
        header:{"Content-type":"application/json"}   
    }).then(response=>response.json()).then(json => console.log(json)).catch(err=>console.log(err));

}
```

that is put into my signup.html right before body tag is closed and used onclick of a button

```
<input id="pass" style = "color:black;" type="text"/>
<button onclick="AuthUp()">Generate Key For a New Wallet<button>
```

which fetch-posts to the API endpoint...

```
app.post('/api/SignUp',(req,res)=>
{
  const { pass } = req.body;

  console.log(`pass is ${pass}`);

  auth.SignUp(pass);

  res.json('200');
});
```

my body parser. Says it is deprecated on vscode.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The body parser seems to be fine since it parses data I send through postman on other endpoints.

for further processing. I can confirm that it gives me undefined when printing it to console after initializing the req.body object. What is it that I am doing wrong? I am pretty sure it is a stupid mistake, my eyes have been lazy from coding. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: are you using expressjs? do you have any body-parser middleware?

Comment: I do indeed. But now that you mention it, it seems like the one I am using is deprecated

Comment: perhaps ... but you haven't shown how you use it, so it may be you're using it wrong

Comment: I can assure you it has been working for a long time, or I would have posted it. But it does look deprecated, it is posted @JaromandaX

Comment: There is a built in parser you can use: `express.json()`

Comment: I actually changed to that after the last person suggested it might have to do with the parser. In my question I mentioned that it works with my other endpoints. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a standard "form" to post data to the api and it worked. I honestly do not know why sending the value of the input via a button and js to my middleware returned as undefined.